Connect Flow created in Twilio Studio to a Twilio Phone Number via Terraform
I would like to connect flow that created in Twilio Studio to a Twilio Phone Number via Terraform.
In browser URL this possibility is under following URL:
phone-numbers/manage/incoming/PN<number>/configure
During apply I saw that's calling following API:
console/phone-numbers/api/v1/configure-number/PN<number>
(but couldn't find body of this call TBH)
Question is how to do this via Terraform, or is it even possible?
TF GitHub:
https://github.com/twilio/terraform-provider-twilio
Checked the possibility in Terraform, as only documentation is a code in repo.

This is a provider problem, not terraform. There is an open issue which is there for almost two years. But downloading the provider shouldn't be an issue and with syntax highlighting you should be able to see if and how you can connect the two.

@MarkoE syntax highlighting is not working - at least for me. Even after terraform init with provided twilio provider. Doing the same way like for i.e. azurerm Azure provider. However I was just checking the available resources in Twilio Terraform Github. Just cannot find such possibility. I know its provider issue, not terraform itself, although it's Twilio Collective and was redirect to SO during creating GitHub issue

Highlighting is working. I probably had a problem with VS cache, but still it's not possible via terraform.

Yeah, so that's a provider issue then. I would suggest opening an issue or a feature request in the Twilio provider repo.
